# How to make a better `Sort` in my case

Tags: files-and-directories, sorting

I have some file names like this:

```
fileNames = {"F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\62.jpg", 
   "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\1.jpg", "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\2.jpg", 
   "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\3.jpg", "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\4.jpg", 
   "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\5.jpg", "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\6.jpg", 
   "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\7.jpg", "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\42.jpg", 
   "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\52.jpg"};
```

I want get a better order for they.But when I use `Sort` for this

```
Sort@fileNames
```

Then I get:

> {"F:\mathematica\liu3\1.jpg", "F:\mathematica\liu3\2.jpg", \
>   "F:\mathematica\liu3\3.jpg", "F:\mathematica\liu3\42.jpg", \
>   "F:\mathematica\liu3\4.jpg", "F:\mathematica\liu3\52.jpg", \
>   "F:\mathematica\liu3\5.jpg", "F:\mathematica\liu3\62.jpg", \
>   "F:\mathematica\liu3\6.jpg", "F:\mathematica\liu3\7.jpg"}

But actually this ordering is my expectation

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So how to get this list with my ordering by a terse method?

Comment: You are getting the same sort order as your OS give you, i.e., lexical order. The easiest way to fix this is not in _Mathematica_, but in your file system. Rename flies such as 3.jpg to 03.jpg or to 30.jpg, whichever way seem more useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for you advices.1)I have try some order in my *Window 10*,but have no my expected order,and I have not found that order you mean like [lexical order](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq2Fj.png).2)The original name is 3.jpg,4.jpg or 42.jpg.to add that 0 is little troublesome.3)I wanna sort it in `mma` because of I wannt import it into `mma` then convenient to following processing

Comment: Your screenshot looks quite strange, where's Name(名称)? And I can't find fonts related options in my OS, I'm using Win10, too.

Comment: @xzczd [Click](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kFezs.png) the More(更多).

Comment: You should check 排序方式, not 分组依据 囧

Comment: @xzczd Yep.Actually I did.Just maked a mistake when I shot the screenshot for you. :)

Comment: I did check More when posting the previous comment but can't find options that seem to related to fonts, maybe they're not translated to 字体, I'm not sure.

Comment: @xzczd Maybe :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this one?:

```
SortBy[#, FileBaseName] &@fileNames
```

Comment: brilliant work ! +1

Comment: I just noticed @xzczd's comment, which I agree with, that your file naming convention is not clear. For instance, does "123" mean the 23rd in the 1st group, or 3rd in 12th group? Better solution would be figured out were more clear naming convention provided.

Comment: Yep,I'm aware of that confict.So I have already deleted it.Thank for your help. :)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know `"."` doesn't take part in sorting.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?:

```
#[[Ordering[StringTake[FileBaseName@# <> "0", 2] & /@ #]]] &@fileNames
```

Comment: As you promption of `FileBaseName`,then I get another try like `fileNames[[Ordering[StringPadRight[FileBaseName/@fileNames,Automatic,"0"]]]]`,Thank you very much.

Comment: @yode Oh, so there're functions for string padding in v10. (I'm still in v9. )

Comment: I don' t know whether or not appropriate I update this post.

Comment: @yode Then since the serial number isn't limited to 0~9, your naming rule turns out to be unclear. For example, should "42" be taken as "42, 1st" or "4, 2nd"?

Comment: Seems to be little unclear,But in my casy "42" mean "4, 2nd"

Comment: @yode Then why it doesn't mean "42, 1st"? Is the serial number limited to 1~10? (Notice that even "12" will cause trouble! )

Comment: Thanks for your commet.I realized that there are conflicts in that update.And I have already deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

there is a nasty way of doing this:

```
orig = (Riffle[ToCharacterCode[fileNames], (Characters /@ fileNames)]) // 
Partition[#, 2] & // Thread[#] & /@ # & // #[[All, {21, 22}]] &

(*{{{54, "6"}, {50, "2"}}, {{49, "1"}, {46, "."}}, {{50, "2"}, {46,"."}},
{{51, "3"}, {46, "."}}, {{52, "4"}, {46, "."}}, {{53,"5"}, {46, "."}},
{{54, "6"}, {46, "."}}, {{55, "7"}, {46,"."}}, {{52, "4"}, {50, "2"}},
{{53, "5"}, {50, "2"}}} *)

sorted = Flatten[Position[orig, #] &/@ Sort@orig]

(* {2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 6, 10, 7, 1, 8} *)

fileNames[[sorted]]

(* {"F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\1.jpg", "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\2.jpg",
"F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\3.jpg", "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\4.jpg",
"F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\42.jpg", "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\5.jpg",
"F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\52.jpg", "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\6.jpg",
"F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\62.jpg", "F:\\mathematica\\liu3\\7.jpg"} *)
```

Comment: you are welcome !